# Azure function app: Code is getting deployed in another function app

Tags: azure, deployment, azure-functions

I have two function apps A and B. Whenever I am deploying code in function app A it gets deployed in both A and B. similarly if I try to deploy code in function app B it gets deployed in app A as well. how can I debug this issue. I am using VS Code and azure extension for deployment.

Comment: How are you deploying?

Comment: Using VS code azure extension. its a manual deployment in dev environment

Answer (score 1):

This was due to a configuration WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE in function app A having value as name of function app B.